# The FOR command fails to work (only in case if it used without recursive key)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to figure out why FOR command fails to work as expected.

Here is the structure of my files and folders:

```
Test
|
|------ foo.txt
|------ bar.txt
|
|------ Exclude
        (here placed files that should not be processed)
          |
          |------ aaa.txt
          |------ bbb.txt
```

The task is to process foo.txt and bar.txt and also avoid to process aaa.txt and bbb.txt.

Below are 3 ways that I tried.

The 1st way. It's work, but since it require `/r` (recursive) key, it doesn't satisfy my needs.

```
for /r "C:\Test" %f in (*.txt) do type %f
```

The 2nd way. That's what I'm trying to do. It doesn't work. Insted, it gives me the error: **"C:\Test" was unexpected at this time**.

```
for "C:\Test" %f in (*.txt) do type %f
```

The 3rd way. It works and currently I use it as workaround, but I'm still wondering why the 2nd approach fails.

```
cd "C:\Test"
for %f in (*.txt) do type %f
```

Comment: Another formulation of the 3rd way that maintains the original current directory: `pushd "C:\test"` / `for %f in ...` / `popd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the `for /?` help it is indicated that, without the `/r` switch, the syntax for the base `for` command is

```dos
for %var in (set) do ...
```

That is, you can not include the folder where you are doing it.

As you need to process the files inside `c:\Test`, then your set are the files inside that folder, so

```dos
for %a in ("c:\Test\*.txt") do type "%a"
```

*note*: remember that inside a batch file the percent signs in the `for` replaceable parameters need to be doubled

```dos
for %%a in ("c:\Test\*.txt") do type "%%a"
```